# Can I configure 'HtmlWeb' that it automatically converts html entities?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-core-2.0

I am using an `HtmlWeb` object from `HtmlAgilityPack` to query text from an website:

```
HtmlDocument lHmtlDoc = new HtmlWeb().Load("http://www.my-website.de");

var lValue1 = lHmtlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='item-1']").InnerHtml;
var lValue2 = lHmtlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='item-2']").InnerHtml;
// ... 100 further different values selected
```

My Problem: All values containing HTML-Entities like: "Text `&nbsp;` Text `&amp;` Text ..."

I want to convert these html entities to text. I could do this:

```
lValue1 = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(lValue1);
lValue2 = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(lValue2);
// ... 100 more
```

But this solution is a bad approach because the code is getting untidy and it is too much work to do this for each item.

Is it possible to configure HtmlWeb so that it automatically converts html entities?

Comment: Which library did you use for `HtmlWeb`? For `lHmtlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='item-2']").InnerHtml`, I got error that there is no `InnerHtml` for `HtmlNodeCollection`. If you mean `HtmlAgilityPack`, there is no directly to get decode text from `HtmlNode`, you could try to implement your extension method by combing the two part codes.

Comment: yes, it is the HtmlAgilityPack.

Comment: For `SelectNodes("//div[@class='item-1']").InnerHtml`, it is invalidate, there is no `InnerHtml` for `SelectNodes`

Comment: @Tao Zhou: you are right. I have fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to implementing extension methods for `HtmlNode`

```
    public static class HtmlAgilityPackExtensions
{
    public static string InnerHtmlDecode(this HtmlNode htmlNode)
    {
        return System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(htmlNode.InnerHtml);
    }
}
```

Use

```
 var result2 = lHmtlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='item-1']").InnerHtmlDecode();
```